# How to define variable inside of a text widget using another variable in a separate dart file in Flutter says its undefine

Tags: flutter, dart, bluetooth

I am building an app that receives messages from an Arduino with HC06 and one of the thing I would like it to do is to display the values the Arduino indicating a sensor's value every 30 seconds it sends a new value. Here is my DisplayInfo.dart file that needs to be able to just read the variable.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bluetooth_serial/flutter_bluetooth_serial.dart';
import 'dart:typed_data';
import './BackgroundCollectingTask.dart';
import './GraphPage.dart';
import 'dart:async';

class DisplayInfo extends StatefulWidget {
  const DisplayInfo({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  _DisplayInfoState createState() => _DisplayInfoState();
}

class _DisplayInfoState extends State<DisplayInfo> {

  // BluetoothConnection? connection;
  // bool isConnecting = true;
  // bool get isConnected => (connection?.isConnected ?? false);
  //
  // bool isDisconnecting = false;
  //
  // @override
  // void intiState(){
  //   super.initState();
  //   _getBTConnection();
  // }
  //
  // @override
  // void dispose(){
  //   if (isConnected) {
  //     isDisconnecting = true;
  //     connection?.dispose();
  //     connection = null;
  //   }
  //   super.dispose();
  // }
  //
  // _getBTConnection(){
  //   BluetoothConnection.toAddress(widget.server.address).then((_connection){
  //     connection = _connection;
  //     setState(() {
  //       isConnecting = false;
  //       isDisconnecting = false;
  //     });
  //     connection!.input!.listen(_onDataReceived).onDone((){
  //       if(isDisconnecting){
  //         print('Disconnecting locally');
  //       } else {
  //         print('Disconnecting remotely');
  //       }
  //       if(this.mounted){
  //         setState(() {});
  //       }
  //       Navigator.of(context).pop();
  //
  //     });
  //   }).catchError((error){
  //     Navigator.of(context).pop();
  //   });
  // }
  //
  // void _onDataReceived(Uint8List data){
  //
  // }

  Color tempColor = Colors.grey.shade400;
  Color humidColor = Colors.grey.shade400;
  Color co2Color = Colors.grey.shade400;
  Color vocColor = Colors.grey.shade400;
  Color pm25Color = Colors.grey.shade400;
  Color ozoneColor = Colors.grey.shade400;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)  {
  final BackgroundCollectingTask task =
  BackgroundCollectingTask.of(context, rebuildOnChange: true);
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title:const Text('Information Display', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.pinkAccent,
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  child: const Text('Graph Chart'),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const GraphInfo()),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ),
              Row(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(20,10,20,10),
                    child: Container(
                        child: const Text('Values', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20))
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(30,10,30,10),
                    child: Container(
                      child: const Text('Levels', style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 20)),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                children: [
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 350.0,
                    height: 50.0,
                    child: Card(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment(-0.85, 0.00),
                        child: Text(
                          'Temperature ' + temperature,
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                        ), //Text
                      ), //Center
                    ), //Card
                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 350.0,
                    height: 50.0,
                    child: Card(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment(-0.85, 0.00),
                        child: Text(
                          'Humidity',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                        ), //Text
                      ), //Center
                    ), //Card

                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 350.0,
                    height: 50.0,
                    child: Card(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment(-0.85, 0.00),
                        child: Text(
                          'CO2',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                        ), //Text
                      ), //Center
                    ), //Card

                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 350.0,
                    height: 50.0,
                    child: Card(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment(-0.85, 0.00),
                        child: Text(
                          'VOC',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                        ), //Text
                      ), //Center
                    ), //Card

                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 350.0,
                    height: 50.0,
                    child: Card(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment(-0.85, 0.00),
                        child: Text(
                          'PM2.5',
                          style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                        ), //Text
                      ), //Center
                    ), //Card

                  ),
                  SizedBox(
                    width: 350.0,
                    height: 50.0,
                    child: Card(
                      color: Colors.grey.shade400,
                      child: Align(
                        alignment: Alignment(-0.85, 0.00),
                          child: Text(
                              'Ozone',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                        ), //Text
                      ), //Center
                    ), //Card
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0,20,0,10),
                    child: SizedBox(
                      width: 350.0,
                      height: 125.0,
                      child: Card(
                        color: Colors.purpleAccent,
                        child: Align(
                          alignment: Alignment.centerLeft,
                          child: Text(
                            'System Status',
                            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black, fontSize: 16),
                          ), //Text
                        ), //Center
                      ), //Card
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),


            ],
          )

      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My second page collecting data via bluetooth which checks for if there is any data to be received by the arduino.

```
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_bluetooth_serial/flutter_bluetooth_serial.dart';
import 'package:scoped_model/scoped_model.dart';

class DataSample {
  double temperature;
  double humidity;
  double co2;
  double voc;
  double pm25;
  double ozone;
  DateTime timestamp;

  DataSample({
    required this.temperature,
    required this.humidity,
    required this.co2,
    required this.voc,
    required this.pm25,
    required this.ozone,
    required this.timestamp,
  });
}

class BackgroundCollectingTask extends Model {
  static BackgroundCollectingTask of(
      BuildContext context, {
        bool rebuildOnChange = false,
      }) =>
      ScopedModel.of<BackgroundCollectingTask>(
        context,
        rebuildOnChange: rebuildOnChange,
      );

  final BluetoothConnection _connection;
  List<int> _buffer = List<int>.empty(growable: true);

  // @TODO , Such sample collection in real code should be delegated
  // (via `Stream<DataSample>` preferably) and then saved for later
  // displaying on chart (or even stright prepare for displaying).
  // @TODO ? should be shrinked at some point, endless colleting data would cause memory shortage.
  List<DataSample> samples = List<DataSample>.empty(growable: true);

  bool inProgress = false;

  BackgroundCollectingTask._fromConnection(this._connection) {
    _connection.input!.listen((data) {
      _buffer += data;

      while (true) {
        // If there is a sample, and it is full sent
        int index = _buffer.indexOf('t'.codeUnitAt(0));
        if (index >= 0 && _buffer.length - index >= 13) {
          final DataSample sample = DataSample(
              temperature: (_buffer[index + 1] + _buffer[index + 2] / 100),
              humidity: (_buffer[index + 3] + _buffer[index + 4] / 100),
              co2: (_buffer[index + 5] + _buffer[index + 6] / 100),
              voc: (_buffer[index + 7] + _buffer[index + 8] / 100),
              pm25: (_buffer[index + 9] + _buffer[index + 10] / 100),
              ozone: (_buffer[index + 11] + _buffer[index + 12] / 100),
              timestamp: DateTime.now());
          _buffer.removeRange(0, index + 13);

          samples.add(sample);
          notifyListeners(); // Note: It shouldn't be invoked very often - in this example data comes at every second, but if there would be more data, it should update (including repaint of graphs) in some fixed interval instead of after every sample.
          //print("${sample.timestamp.toString()} -> ${sample.temperature1} / ${sample.temperature2}");
        }
        // Otherwise break
        else {
          break;
        }
      }
    }).onDone(() {
      notifyListeners();
    });
  }

  static Future<BackgroundCollectingTask> connect(
      BluetoothDevice server) async {
    final BluetoothConnection connection =
    await BluetoothConnection.toAddress(server.address);
    return BackgroundCollectingTask._fromConnection(connection);
  }

  void dispose() {
    _connection.dispose();
  }

}
```